# Tensorflow 2.1.0 - DLL load failed - windows cpu

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, version, cpu

Installation of TensorFlow 2.1.0 was successful, but TensorFlow import failed.

Open question:

Is there a library that is in a different location/not installed on the system that cannot be loaded?

Procedure for reproduction:

1) create environment

```
conda create --name tensorflow21_env
```

2) activate environment

```
conda activate tensorflow21_env
```

3) install

1. `conda install python=3.7`
2. `pip install tensorflow-cpu  #install tensorflow=2.1.0;`

4) test

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf"
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

**Installation Output:**

**Output: conda install python=3.7**

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env

  added / updated specs:
    - python=3.7


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/win-64::ca-certificates-2020.1.1-0
  certifi            pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2019.11.28-py37_0
  openssl            pkgs/main/win-64::openssl-1.1.1d-he774522_4
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-20.0.2-py37_1
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.7.6-h60c2a47_2
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-45.2.0-py37_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.31.1-he774522_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.1-h0510ff6_4
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_1
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.34.2-py37_0
  wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py37_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

The dependency walker confirms that all DLLs could be loaded ([download dependency walker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)).

[dependency_trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sSOD.png)

Addon: 
path for dependency walker

```
C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow21_env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd
```

**Update:**

My processor supports neither AVX nor AVX2 and therefore the tensorflow pip package could not be installed or to be more precise the tensorflow package could not be imported.

**Interim solution:**

The interim solution for legacy & low-end CPU without AVX support is to install SSE-prebuild-binaries for tensorflow.
Go to [tensorflow-windows-wheel](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel) and follow instruction to install either tensorflow 2.0.0 or 2.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this method:**

Uninstall the TensorFlow package that you installed using pip and reinstall using ***conda install tensorflow*** this may work! Now you can import TensorFlow without problems. I hope this can help you.

**If you need more detailed steps. Here, you can do the following below.**

- Run the anaconda prompt as an administrator. (right click-> run as administrator).
- `pip uninstall tensorflow`
- Close anaconda prompt.
- Again run anaconda prompt as administrator.
- type:

  `conda install tensorflow`

  It will ask for some `y / n`

  Type `y`.

Now after all done, change your python interpreter's environment to anaconda environment where you installed tensorflow.

- Now try importing tensorflow.

I hope this helps.

Comment: has someone tried this answer? I dont want to uninstall tensorflow 2.0 as i struggled to install it?

Comment: i tried conda install tensorflow as uninstalling it. (1) i dont get the message that TF installed successfully (2)  when I import tensorflow i get an error ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.i am really struggling as i thought the instruction here will help me  https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/install-tensorflow-2-0-along-with-all-packages-on-anaconda-for-windows-10-and-ubuntu-86a89ba51983